# Automating login in simulation with Internet Explorer

Tags: authentication, automation

I am using enterprise environment and no installations are allowed.
What I need is to create some kind of script to do several things:

1. Open an Internet Explorer website (with this browser).
2. Website window must be clicked to activate it and navigate using TAB key at least 20 times to get a new link which opens a new window (java) to enter values.
3. Those values are "user" and "password", I can navigate between fields using TAB. So I need to enter a string (or keypress simulation to enter a word) for USER, pres TAB, enter another string for PASSWORD, press TAB twice and then ENTER.

Is it possible?

I tried batch scripts, "autohotkey" and "PhraseExpress" stuff with no results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Perhaps this will help. I use a version of this daily.
Copy script to notepad, save with extension .ahk
For instance... PW-sender.ahk
Alter and edit to your satisfaction.

EDIT:  This is assuming you have AutoHotkey V1 installed.

```
/*    NOTES 

• Required: Upper and lower case letters, a number, and a special character(! <--change as wanted... or remove).
• Used personally for required password changes every 3 months at work. 
• Anyone with access to your script also has access to your login credentials.

• Change "YourUserName" in Globals to your personal User Name, retaining the quote marks.
• Change the different "PassWords" to your personal Passwords, adding or removing extras as shown.

• Useage in below Example:  
    * Pressing (Ctrl+1) or (Ctrl+Numpad1) will produce...
YourUserName
    PassWord1!
    * Pressing (Ctrl+2) or (Ctrl+Numpad2) will produce...
YourUserName
    PassWord2!
    * Pressing (Ctrl+3) or (Ctrl+Numpad3) will produce...
YourUserName
    PassWord3!
*/


#Persistent
#SingleInstance, Force
Menu, Tray, Icon, shell32.dll, 44

;  PART 1  ∙=∙=∙=∙Globals∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙ 
usrnm := "YourUserName"
pswd := ["PassWord1", "PassWord2", "PassWord3"]
;;∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙ 

;  PART 2  ∙=∙=∙=∙Send Variable∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙ 
^1::
    ^Numpad1::
^2::
    ^Numpad2::
^3::
    ^Numpad3::
^4::
    ^Numpad4::

    SendInput, %usrnm%`n{Tab}
        SendInput, % "{Text}" pswd[SubStr(A_ThisHotkey, 0)] "!`n"
Return
;;∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙=∙ 

^Home:: 
    Reload
        Return
^Esc::
    ExitApp
        Return
```

Comment: Thanks in advance. But installations are not allowed in my computer (admin work policies). So I can't install AutoHotKey or similar...